# Vim color scheme similar to the one used in jsfiddle?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I really like the color scheme used in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Is there any color scheme that it is similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see anything at your link, but why don't you judge for yourself?  You can see most of the publicly available color schemes for Vim here:
http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-pl.html

Just click on the name of any of the colorschemes to download.  Try a bunch of them, modify to suit your tastes if you can't find one that's perfect for you.

Comment: Not very conclusive, nor recently updated (last: 2009-09-26), but a better starting point than most.