# JsFiddle-like color scheme

Tags: color-scheme, codehighlighter

I search for code highlighting color scheme as similar as possible to light scheme in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net). I found only this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437617/vim-color-scheme-similar-to-the-one-used-in-jsfiddle), I do not consider it satisfactory.
So, there is a similar [scheme](https://studiostyl.es/schemes/jsfiddle), but only for VS. Any other variants?

Comment: Im looking for the new jsfiddle (Dark)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are no other variants as of today :(